# How to create a Request Object in Ajax for Only modern browsers

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, request-object

I want to make a javascript function to create a Request Object in Ajax. I want it to work for modern browsers only, and the question is: do I really need to difference between two possibilities?

```
function createRequestObject(){
var reqObj;
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
reqObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}else{
reqObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return reqObj;
}
```

If I use directly the XMLHttpRequest(), would it work in major browsers? Why or why not?

Comment: IE>=7 supports `XMLHttpRequest` object, so how "modern" do you need?

Comment: @Passerby Thanks, this was the info I needed. I also heard about the Level 2 one.